# Add Admin Configuration Tab Images in Magento

Tags: image, magento, configuration, magento-1.7, configurationsection

I want to add image in

Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> "Left Menu Tab" ( Here )

just see following image what i want to do :

[image]

Any Solutions..??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <magepal translate="label" module="magepal">
            <label><![CDATA[<div style="position: absolute;"><img id="magepal_block" src="" alt="" border="0" /></div>&nbsp;<script>$('magepal_block').src = SKIN_URL + "images/magepal/magepal.png";</script>]]></label>
            <sort_order>400</sort_order>
        </magepal>
    </tabs>
```

Put image in (size 158 x 18)

> /skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/magepal/magepal.png

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a cleaner solution would be to add a css class to the tab, then style with a css file defined in an adminhtml layout definition.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <magepal translate="label" module="magepal">
            <label>MagePal</label>
            <sort_order>400</sort_order>
            <class>admin-system-config-magepal</class>
        </magepal>
    </tabs>
    ....
```